# Time Series (White Noise)

Tags: time-series

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$Suppose $\{W_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ are two independent normal white noise series with $\operatorname{Var}(W_t)=2\operatorname{Var}(Y_t)=4$. Let $X_t = W_t-0.5W_{t-1}$ and $Z_t=Y_t+0.4Y_{t-1}-0.4Y_{t-2}$. Put $V_t=X_t-Z_t$. Find the $\Cov(V_t,V_{t-1})$, $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots$

So I tried doing this:

$$\Cov(V_t,V_{t-1}) = E[(W_t-0.5W_{t-1}-Y_t-0.4Y_{t-1}+0.4Y_{t-2})(W_{t-1}-0.5W_{t-2}-Y_{t-1}-0.4Y_{t-2}+0.4Y_{t-3})]$$

For $k=0$, $\Cov(V_t,V_{t-1})=1$

For $k=1$, $\Cov(V_t,V_{t-1})=-4.8$

For $k=2$, $\Cov(V_t,V_{t-1})=-0.8$

For $k>2$, $\Cov(V_t,V_{t-1})=0$

Is this correct? Any help/contribution will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I changed {$W_t$} to $\{W_t\}$, with the $\{\text{braces}\}$ _inside_ the MathJax environment, thereby getting proper spacing and matching of font sizes, and similarly changed $\operatorname{Cov}(V_t,V_{t-1})$=-4.8 to $\operatorname{Cov}(V_t,V_{t-1})=-4.8$ and did some other copy-editing. ${}\qquad{}$